# Searching for many different names in a Panda frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following example code:

```
c1 = ["Mary herself","Mary is mine","John himself","John is mine","Alan himself","Alan is mine"]
s1 = pd.Series(c1)
c2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s2 = pd.Series(c2)

dictionary = {"A":s1,"B":s2}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
print(df)
for i in range(6):
  name = df["A"].iloc[i]
  if "Mary" in name:
    print(name)
  if "Alan" in name:
    print(name)
  else:
    print("no")
```

I want to filter strings that include "Mary" or "Alan". My solution works well for only two cases, but I wonder if there is a more suitable solution for a lot more cases. For example, if I want to filter "John" and "Brown" too, I would already need four if statements.

How can I improve my code so I wouldn't have to add a new if statement for each name I want to filter?

Comment: I see exactly *one* `if:…else:…` - can you make me see the issue with `so many if else`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain clearly. I mean there are two "if:" statement, if I want to filter more people, such as John, Brown,etc. There will be three four or five "if:" statement.
Does this unavoidable? The code will very long and difficult to maintain in the future.

Comment: That is a valid concern, presented understandably: *Put it in the question*!

Comment: I edited the question to better highlight the concern explained in your comment @Samulafish

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will follow all the instructions to make a better thread in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Your code follows this pseudo-code pattern:

```
if any of these strings are in name:
    do x
```

The simplest way to express that in Python is to invert the condition:

```
if name in any of these strings:
    do x
```

Or as actual Python:

```
if name in ["Alan", "Mary"]:
    print(name)
```

Comment: better use a set for containment check `if name in {"Alan", "Mary"}:`

Comment: This is wrong, since `"Mary is herself" in ["Alan", "Mary"]` will return `False`.  @MaartenFabré  `"Mary is herself" in {"Alan", "Mary"}` will return `False` a little faster.

Comment: :facepalm:. Time for the weekend

Answer (score 4):

## elif

Your code doesn't look like it will work the way you intend it to:

```
  if "Mary" in name:
    print(name)
  if "Alan" in name:
    print(name)
  else:
    print("no")
```

If `name` contains `"Mary"`, but does not contain `"Alan"`, you will have two lines printed, due to the first `print(name)` and the `print("no")` statements.  It would also print `name` twice in the string contained both `"Mary"` and `"Alan"`, like "Mary is Alan's"`.

You probably wanted an `if`/`elif`/`else` statement:

```
  if "Mary" in name:
    print(name)
  elif "Alan" in name:
    print(name)
  else:
    print("no")
```

This will print only once per row.

## .startswith

Do you really want in?  Should `"Anne"` match `"Mary-Anne is herself"`?  Or are you looking for `name.startswith("...")` tests?

Should `"Mary"` match `"Maryanne is herself"` or `"Mary-Anne is herself"`?  Maybe you want to add a space to the end of the search term:

```
  if name.startswith("Mary "):
      print(name)
  elif name.startswith("Alan "):
      print(name)
  else
      print(no)
```

Alternately, you may want to split `name` into words, and check for equality.  You'll have to clarify your question.

## or

If you want to do the same thing with multiple conditions, you could link them with `or`:

```
  if name.startswith("Mary ") or name.startswith("Alan "):
      print(name)
  else
      print(no)
```

## any

If you want to test a long list of similar conditions, joined together with `or`, you are really wanting to test if `any` of the conditions match.  Which is perfect for the `any(...)` function, which returns `True` if any of the conditions is `True`.

Combined `any()` with a generator expression, to generate a series of conditions to test:

```
prefixes = ["Mary ", "Alan "]
for i in range(6):
    name = df["A"].iloc[i]
    if any(name.startwith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes):
        print(name)
    else:
        print("no")
```

## Loop like a native

Why are you looping over indices, and then extracting the data by index?  Why hard-code the length of the range?

```
prefixes = ["Mary ", "Alan "]
for name in df["A"]:
    if any(name.startwith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes):
        print(name)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 2):

If your series has many more rows than you have names to check (which should be the case), you should use the vectorized string functions in `pandas`.

```
names = ["Mary", "Alan"]
names_re = "|".join(names)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Mary herself","Mary is mine","John himself","John is mine","Alan himself","Alan is mine"],
                   "B": [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df[df["A"].str.contains(names_re)]

#               A  B
# 0  Mary herself  1
# 1  Mary is mine  2
# 4  Alan himself  5
# 5  Alan is mine  6
```

This is because iterating over a series using Python is much slower than these vectorized functions which are run in C. Note that the combined search string is a regex looking for any of the names. Don't do this if you a hundred names or more.

Comment: Again, without start-of-line (`^`) and word-break (`\b`) patterns in the regex, this would match `"Alana is herself"` and `"Avoid Typhoid-Mary like the plague"`, which may not be intended.

Comment: @AJNeufeld It also may be intended. This answer reproduces the behavior in the OP (except for the different output format). The regex can be modified for different things if needed.